# C# Selenium Chrome port issue?

Tags: c#, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to use *selenium* with C# and chrome but it fails to connect.

My code:

```
string site = "https://google.de";
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\test\");
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(site);
```

Both, Chrome and the Chrome driver window are opening after a few seconds after the site has loaded and everything looks fine however, chrome driver is reporting the following:

> Starting ChromeDriver 2.41.578737
>   (49da6702b16031c40d63e5618de03a32ff6c197e) on port 61455 Only local
>   connections are allowed.
>
> DevTools listening on
>   ws://127.0.0.1:61458/devtools/browser/98bab62c-09d8-4714-b51b-4118ed7100c3
>   [1535800947.687][WARNING]: Timed out connecting to Chrome, retrying...

Is it possible that the application is using two different ports and this could lead to the timeout issue?

Comment: @HaNdTriX This is a typical configuration issue and I suppose your binary versions are different from OP's binary versions. You need to update the question with the binary version information to help us construct a canonical answer.

Comment: Yes, the OP needs to update with chrome browser's version as well. And maybe, try update both browser, and webdriver to the latest versions?

Comment: have you updated your chrome browser,   it seems like for your chrome's devmode is on. provide chromeoptions using webdriver.ChromeOptions(); and are you using  chrome in headless mode ?

Answer (score 3):

To fix this issue in the past I simply had to make sure both, Chrome and the Chrome driver were compatible and up-to-date, the best way to do this is to download the latest available versions which at the time of writing are:

- **ChromeDriver** 2.42
- **Chrome** 69.0.3497.100

The latest driver can be downloaded using NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Selenium.Chrome.WebDriver

```
Install-Package Selenium.Chrome.WebDriver -Version 2.42.0
```

Or from the official site if you want to download it manually: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/